# How to display a repeated list with angularjs and html formatting?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show a repeated list, and render each element with `ngSanitize` as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="todo in todos" ng-bind-html="todo.text"/>
```

I get no error in the console, but I also don't get any output. Why?

By the way: the following does actually work, but unformatted markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="todo in todos">{{todo.text}}</div>
```

Comment: Should it be `todos` and not `totos`?  Also, close the quotes on your `ng-repeat`.

Comment: just a typo here, sorry.

Comment: Why `ng-bind-html` and not just `ng-bind` ?

Comment: Because the `text` contains html markup elements like `<strong>test text</strong>`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or a plnkr?

Comment: I'm using `1.4.3-1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there were a few mistakes in your code. The example below should help you further. Remember, Angular doesn't support self closing `<div>`-tags.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myAppCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="todo in totos" ng-bind="todo.text"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("myAppCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.todos = [
        {name: "todo1", text: "This is test todo 1"},
        {name: "todo2", text: "This is test todo 2"},
        {name: "todo3", text: "This is test todo 3"}
    ]
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ABr/38foxe31/

Comment: *"Remember a `<div>`-tag is not self closing"* Except in XHTML, but very few people use XHTML anymore...

Comment: That works. So, if I got you right, I'm not permitted to close like `<div .../>`, but must use the explicit tag again like `<div ...></div>` even if the text between the divs is empty?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VQ6VdSmA8gHVANjAaBZt?p=preview) and tried to replicate your problem, but everything is working fine.

A couple of things to consider:

1) Have you loaded angular-sanitize in your index file? (before app.js)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

2) Have you correctly injected `ngSanitize` in your module?

```
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your hints, which are all correct. Anyways as written above, it turned out I have to explicit close the `</div>` tag.